How to hide warnings that are generated when creating a bundle of globaStyles in the angular-esbuild pipeline
Problem:: during the process of assembling global styles by the angular project builder
"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-esbuild:application",

warning is generated
var(--color-link-accent) is not a color. Falling back to "dark" tone. [plugin angular-sass].

Is there any way to filter.. hide.. suppress this warning?
architect": {
  build": {
    builder": "@angular-builders/custom-esbuild:application",
    options": {
    plugins": ["esbuild/build-svg-sprites.ts"],
    styles": ["styles/styles-common.scss"], <<-- globalStyles
    polyfills": ["./polyfills.ts"],

I debugged the angular-esbuild source code and realized that the problem occurs when assembling globalStyles
Did I understand right -- I cannot filter this warning from a custom plugin by
build.onEnd((result){ result.warnings = result.warnings.filter(() => ...) })

<<- because it occurs in a completely different build process?
What should I do?
When the webpack builder was used, the problem was solved amazingly simply::
module.exports = (config, options) => {
  config.ignoreWarnings = [
    {
      // Suppress the 'var() is not a color. Falling back to "dark" tone' warning.
      // The error occurs because we use CSS variables to define theme colors.
      module: /\.scss/,
      message: /\.* is not a color. Falling back to "dark" tone./,
    },
  ];
  return config;
};

Who can tell me how to solve my problem in the pipeline of builder angular-esbuild?
Has no one ever encountered such a problem? I won't believe it(

There is an open issue very similar to yours.
